# How should I write an array that should be saved in heap?

Tags: c

I wrote this till now:

```c
int *p;
p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int[]));
```

did I wrong?

I was expecting write a size of the array but without that the programme functions, right?

Comment: Please use the code block format next time, it looked like `p` was just an `int`.

Comment: `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘int[]’` you should get this kind of error

Comment: How will the compiler be able to tell how big an array of **unspecified size** will be?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int *p;
> p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int[]));
> ```
>
> did I wrong?

The code is not valid C.  `int[]` is the type name of an incomplete type, and as such, it is not a valid operand of the `sizeof` operator.  This violates a language constraint, so a conforming C implementation is required to emit a diagnostic when it processes the code presented.

> I was expecting write a size of the array but without that the
> programme functions, right?

If you are saying that a program containing the code presented compiles and runs successfully then that is surprising, but ultimately it means nothing.  The program has undefined behavior as far as the C language specification is concerned, but that does not mean that a compiler must reject it (after emitting the required diagnostic), or that it must fail at runtime. Other than the diagnostic, the spec doesn't say *anything* about what will happen -- that's what "undefined behavior" means.

Comment: So I  had to write  like the sizeof(int[255]) for example. I mean the size should be defined right?

Comment: @MacitSalur, I already wrote that C does not permit you to omit the size.  For absolute clarity, however, yes, the `sizeof` expression is valid when you *include* a valid size.  In particular, your `sizeof(int[255])` is fine.

Comment: can be better to write 255 * sizeof(int) to highlight you ask for 255 int